# MySQL Order By and a Limit 1 subquery to return most recent record

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've noticed there are a few similar questions on StackOverflow, but nothing has worked for me so far. I'll try to keep this as short as possible.

I am building a query that needs to return a number of issues that may or may not have contracts, that may or may not be completed (completed_at would be set to a DateTime, not nil). Each row needs to include:

- one row containing `all` the `issue` record's fields
- the `description` from the `budget_item`
- the `completed_at` date from the **most recent** `contract` that was completed (one `budget_item` could have 0 `contracts`, 1 `contract`, or 5+ `contracts` and any number of them could be open (completed_at :nil) or closed (completed_at: DateTime)

This is what I have so far (which returns the correct number of rows, but it is returning the most recently created contract, not the most recent

```
BaseItem.issues
   .joins('LEFT JOIN budget_items 
           ON issues.id = budget_items.issue_id 
           LEFT JOIN contracts 
           ON budget_items.id = contracts.budget_item_id')
   .select('issues.*, budget_items.description, contracts.completed_at AS resolved_at')
   .group('issues.id')
   .order('contracts.completed_at')
```

The code in the models is as follows:

```
class BaseItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :issues
    ...
end

class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :base_item
    has_many :budget_items
    ...
end

class BudgetItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :issue
    has_many :contracts
    ...
end

class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :budget_item
    ...
end
```

The end result needs to be something along the line of:

There will likely be multiple `issues` making up the different rows. Each `issue` has at least four `budget_items` which are used only for the `budget_item.description` which needs to appear in the final query and then are used to join each `issue` to its many `contracts` (each `budget_item` could have 2 or 3 `contracts` so the `issue` could end up having 8-12 `contracts`. From those `contracts`, the query needs to order them according to their `completed_at` attribute and return `AS resolved_at` only the most recent `contract`'s `completed_at` date. If there were 4 contracts, two had `completed_at: nil`, the query should return the most recent of the two remaining `completed_at` dates as the `resolved_at` field of that particular `issue`.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated and please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

-Dave

The resulting query (from a comment):

```
SELECT  issues.*, budget_items.description, contracts.completed_at AS resolved_at
    FROM  issues
    LEFT JOIN  budget_items ON issues.id = budget_items.issue_id
    LEFT JOIN  contracts ON budget_items.id = contracts.budget_item_id
    WHERE  issues.base_item_id = 6
    GROUP BY  issues.id
    ORDER BY  contracts.completed_at DESC
    LIMIT  1
```

Comment: It is clear from the question that you don't want to see all `contracts`, but only the most recent for an `issue`. What is not quite clear is - `budget_items`. The number of returned rows should be the same as the number of `issues`, or the number of `budget_items` that belong to these `issues`? Say, you have 10 `issues`, each issue has 4 `budget_items`. The final result should have 10 rows or 40 rows? It usually helps if you provide some good representative sample data and what final result should look like based on this sample data. Eliminates a lot of guesses.

Comment: Sorry Vladimir and thanks! I need to be careful about how much information I put out as some of this is confidential, thank you for bearing with me. The final result should only have the 10 rows--I know it's confusing but I only need to join on the first `budget_item` of each `issue`; it is only used for the `description` on the `budget_item` and to join the `contracts`. You are right that I don't need all `contracts`, just the last (most recent) one that has a `completed_at` date set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to show your actual data in the sample to make it useful...

This is what I mean by it. You could have put into your question the following sample data:

**issues**

```
id    base_item_id
--    ------------
10               6
20               6
30               6
99             123
```

**budget_items**

```
id    issue_id    description
--    --------    -----------
 1          10    'one contract, none completed'
 2          20    'one contract, one completed'
 3          30    'two contracts, one completed'
 4          30    'three contracts, two completed'
```

**contracts**

```
id    budget_item_id    completed_at
--    --------------    ------------
 1                 1            NULL
 2                 2      2015-01-02
 3                 3      2015-01-03
 4                 3            NULL
 5                 4      2015-01-05
 6                 4            NULL
 7                 4      2015-01-07
```

**expected result**

```
issues.id    contracts.completed_at    budget_item.description
---------    ----------------------    -----------------------
       10                      NULL    NULL
       20                2015-01-02    one contract, one completed
       30                2015-01-07    three contracts, two completed
```

[Here is SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fb84/1/0).

Is it what you want? Does my sample data cover all possible edge cases? If not, add more rows to it and show how it affects the result.

---

This is how the final query may look like. MySQL doesn't have things like `CROSS APPLY` or `LATERAL JOINS`, so it is less efficient than in other databases - the subquery will run twice.

I have no idea how to translate this SQL to Ruby - I never used Ruby.

```
SELECT
    issues.*
    ,(
        SELECT contracts.completed_at
        FROM
            budget_items
            INNER JOIN contracts ON contracts.budget_item_id = budget_items.id
        WHERE
            budget_items.issue_id = issues.id
            AND contracts.completed_at IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY contracts.completed_at DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS resolved_at
    ,(
        SELECT budget_items.description
        FROM
            budget_items
            INNER JOIN contracts ON contracts.budget_item_id = budget_items.id
        WHERE
            budget_items.issue_id = issues.id
            AND contracts.completed_at IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY contracts.completed_at DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS description
FROM issues
WHERE issues.base_item_id = 6
```

The main idea is simple. We return one row for each `issue`. For each issue we find one latest `contract` using whatever conditions you need (like `contracts.completed_at IS NOT NULL` to look for completed contracts only).

If there is no completed `contracts` at all for an `issue` it returns `NULL` for `description` and `resolved_at`. You can add extra filter in the main `SELECT` to remove such rows if this is what you want (`WHERE issues.base_item_id = 6 AND resolved_at IS NOT NULL`).

Comment: Thank you sincerely Vlad for the extremely detailed answer; I'll check it first thing in the morning.

Comment: Vlad, thanks again for your help; I was able to make that work how I needed it to! Also, query might be simple for you but I'm still relatively new to SQL (using Rails doesn't help!) so it was quite a bit tougher for me :). Really appreciate all the time you put into this, excellent answer and explanation.

Comment: @DerProgrammer, you are welcome. I meant to say that the main idea of the query is simple: select all issues, for each issue lookup the necessary contract, and lookup the necessary description.

Answer (score 1):

```
.order('contracts.completed_at DESC LIMIT 1')
```

(or do I not understand what is missing from your code?)

Comment: Rick that doesn't change the order of the data returned (it doesn't change it with `ASC LIMIT 1` either for some reason) but thank you for trying! I'm hoping to have a eureka moment any time now, but it's been a while already =/

Comment: Is there only one row in `contracts`?  Can you display the constructed `SELECT` statement -- I want to know what RoR did with it.

Comment: 'SELECT issues.*, budget_items.description, contracts.completed_at AS resolved_at FROM `issues` LEFT JOIN budget_items ON issues.id = budget_items.issue_id LEFT JOIN contracts ON budget_items.id = contracts.budget_item_id WHERE `issues`.`base_item_id` = 6 GROUP BY issues.id ORDER BY contracts.completed_at DESC LIMIT 1'

Comment: Remove both `LEFTs` to see if it changes things.

Comment: Still returns the same `contract`.